Artin 10.2.1: Prove that the standard three-dimensional representation of the tetrahedral group T is irreducible as a complex representation.
Artin 10.2.1: Prove that the standard three-dimensional representation of the tetrahedral group T is irreducible as a complex representation.
I am new to representation theory. I have thought about this question for a while but I am stuck. Here is what I have tried:
Let $t$ be a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ centered at the origin with real vertices
$$\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$$
The elements of $T$ can be identified with permutations in $A_4$, which act on the set of vertices. Any three vertices are a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$, and if $g\in T$, then the linear transformation induced by $g$ is uniquely determined by how $g$ permutes the four vertices (since if $x=a_1v_i+a_2v_j+a_3v_k$, then $gx=a_1gv_i+a_2gv_j+a_3gv_k$).
Now I think if I showed that the $T$-orbit of each nonzero $x\in \mathbb{C}^3$ contains $3$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$, that would get me through. If $x=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$, then I would need to find $g_1x$ and $g_2x$ such that $x,g_1x,g_2x$ are linearly independent. I am not sure how to do this, and I think it's likely there is some fact from linear algebra that will make this easy, but I also wouldn't be surprised if I was overlooking something.
If there is any other way to solve this problem other than what I am doing it'd be extremely helpful for me to hear.

hint: one of the matrices in the standard rep is the companion matrix for $x^3-1$ so you know exactly what its eigenvectors look like [slices of a vandermonde matrix] and you can just check that they aren't eigenvectors for the other (diaonal) matrices; recall being reducible for a 3 dim rep means there is a common eigenvector
